# How can I change constraints of a UIView after the UIView is configured?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `ViewController` which contains a `UICollectionView` (vertical scroll). I set up everything programmatically.

First my app retrieves data from Firebase and saves it in an array, then the array elements are displayed in one cell each.

Because I don't know how many cells the `UICollectionView` will have I cannot set a heightAnchor constraint with a proper value. Normally I would set the heightAnchor constraint to something like `CGFloat(myArray.count * 450)` however at the point in time when the `UICollectionView` gets configured the array is empty because Firebase is asynchronous.

Using `.isScrollEnabled = true` with a preset height is in this case not an option because I would like the whole view (which also contains other components) to be scrollable. Thats why the UICollectionView needs to be big enough to show all elements.

Comment: While it may be possible (set the constraint constant when the collection view's content size changes), you're fighting against the default behavior. Maybe a `UICollectionView` is not the right approach to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to update all cells. After you fetch the data you need to make a refresh:

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thank you but I already do update all cells however the UICollectionView gets configured before the Firebase data gets saved in the Array. When the data then is saved in the array its already to late, at the time the UICollectionView is configured the number of elements in the array is zero. Thats why I can't set the UICollectionViews heightAnchor.constraint to something like CGFloat(myArray.count * 450)

Comment: did you try  cell.layoutIfNeeded()